# Change value of Tag in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, xml, local-storage

I have the LocalStorage XML called classification where I save the name of teams and their points.

I want to go to tag points and change value over time I add a new result.

My localstorage is:

```
 <classification><classification id="1"><name>SL Benfica</name><points>0</points ></classification>
<classification id="2"><name>FC Porto</name ><points>0</points></classification>
<classification id="3"><name>Sporting CP</name><points>0</points></classification>
<classification id="4"><name>SC Braga</name><points>0</points></classification>
</classification>
```

I want to read the value of points and add +3 when I add a new result of a game.

Javascript:

```
if (localStorage.classification){

    parser = new DOMParser();

    var doc =parser.parseFromString(localStorage.classification,"text/xml");
    var n = doc.getElementsByTagName("classification")[0].childNodes.length;
    var i = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    elem = doc.getElementsByTagName("classification")[0].childNodes[i];
    equipaclassificacao = elem.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    if (resultgame == 1) {    
         pointsg = Number(elem.getElementsByTagName("points")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);    
         pointsg += 3;
     }
 }
```

Someone know how to resolve this?

Comment: can you show `console.log(elem.getElementsByTagName("points")[0].firstChild)` from within `if` statement?

Comment: no, don't show anything, but if a add .nodeValue in front of firstChild show 0

Comment: I try to show in alert and convert to number and show NaN